# Update APK error

Tags: android, google-play

After making changes to my project I have uploaded it to Google Play. Some time after I've tried to update it (Google Play has been already refresh application info and I saw new version number) but I've got an error - "Error retrieving data from server RPC:S-5:AEC-0...". Same report appears on my other devices (5pcs) and users began to mail me with same problem.
Searching gives me [this support report](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3095281?hl=en). After minutes of googling I found solution - reconnect Google account and it works for me. But I have 40k users - what can I do to help them all? I've implemented new fancy features in game and now they available only for new users.
So, question is - does anybody faced already with such problem? What have you done to solve this?

Comment: Looks like a issue with play service. You may want to re-upload the apk file to make sure the previous upload was not corrupted.

Comment: It's difficult right now - I have uploaded two versions above problematic and users have been installed it.

Comment: I would unpublish the newest version until a solution is found!

Comment: Hmm... maybe it has sense but I found no option to delete APK from Google Play. As I remember it can be done in old version of developer console but seems now I can't remove it.